# Get div to adjust height with header content

Tags: css

I have a side bar that contains two divs. The first div may or may not have content, depending on what else is done on the page. The second div contains a long list of things and has a limited height, so scrolling is possible. I want to have the sidebar be as tall as the page, and I want the list container in the sidebar to be as tall as the sidebar minus the height of the header (which will change while using the page). I don't care about limiting the size of the header. The biggest is will get isn't anything significant.

Right now I'm just setting the height of the list container to be some number that is won't go over a maximized window height if the header div as as much content as it can, but this leaves an empty space at the bottom when the header is empty, and still doesn't work very well if the window is resized.

The layout is similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v6MNx/1/).

Is there a css solution to what I'm looking for, or will I have to use javascript and get window height/set div heights in pixels? I'm fine with either, it just seemed like there should be a CSS way to accomplish it.

Comment: Using Firefox with the Firebug extension, you can view the css/html of any website. Just look at the page you referenced in Firebug for your answer.

Comment: I made that page as a demo of what my page is currently doing that I don't want. The list container height is being hard set and I want it to be the height of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/YWNyr/

CSS tips:

1. If you use 'absolute' positioning, width,height,left,top, etc... is relative to the first ancestor that has a "position" property other than "static", or the body if nothing is there.
2. for static menus, it is common to use 'position:fixed' as it will simplify scrolling issues
3. When using jquery its easier(and faster) to toggle a class than to change the DOM since that requires redrawing of the elements by the browser

-edit: for refreshing the sidebar size some javascript is necessary:

```
$('#headerAdd , #headerRemove').click( function()
  {$('#sideContainer').height($(window).height()-$("#header").height());
} );
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want. The only thing missing is that I'd like the list container to care about the header's content height. i.e. sidecontainer should be 100% of the page height, and the header height should be as large as it needs to be, and the list should be the remainder that wasn't used by the header. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YWNyr/3/) of what causes problems.

Comment: Sorry, You're ganna HAVE to use javascript for that (for a refresh after dom change), after the page renders, the css becomes static.
you can do this in many different ways, but I would just add this to the javascript:

`$('#headerAdd , #headerRemove').click(
        function(){$('#sideContainer').height($(window).height()-$("#header").height());}
);`

Comment: That's what I had guessed, but I'm not even remotely good at CSS so I wasn't going to discount the possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to using a little jQuery, here's a little code snippet that should help you equalize the height of the two divs, no matter which has more content. You can change it to your liking too.

```
var leftHeight = $(".left").height();
var rightHeight = $(".right").height();
var maxHeight = 0;
var div = "";
if (leftHeight >= rightHeight)
{
    maxHeight = leftHeight;
    div = ".right";
}
else
{
    maxHeight = rightHeight;
    div = ".left";
}

$(div).each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$(div).height(maxHeight);
```

and credit where credit is due, this is an edit of a code snipped found at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/equalize-heights-of-divs/)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of your list container to 100%, and your overflow to scroll:

```
#listContainer {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will keep the list in a scrollpane that reaches to the bottom of the page, no matter how large the header grows or shrinks.

Comment: I just changed that on my fiddle page and it isn't doing that. It just puts listContainer in a div sized to fit with scrollbars that don't do anything. http://jsfiddle.net/v6MNx/6/

Comment: This might be because the preview pane resizes to fit the length of your content (and thus doesn't need to be scrolled). Try wrapping everything inside of a div with a fixed height to mimic your actual html page.